# What Gintama episode had this scene?

Tags: gintama

I've read somewhere that there was a scene where Shouyou was released from jail and Gintoki cries upon his return, I've watched all episodes but I don't remember this, can someone tell what episode was it?

Comment: as i remember there is not episode like that, but one thing is clear that shouyou was killed by gintoki

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, they don't meet after he's arrested and yoshida shouyou is never released from jail. The only time they meet is when Oboro forces Gintoki to behead his teacher in order to save his friends. Once he's killed, yoshida shouyou loses control over Utsuro and is presumably killed off as a personality.

You could be referring to the episode where Gintoki is restrained as his teacher is arrested and dragged away from him. Which is shown as a flashback in one of the episodes, but is better explained in the movie I think. It maybe the first or second movie, I'm not sure. Never was a big fan of the movies though.